Are any studies tracking how long it takes Western countries, on average, to deport rejected/ineligible refugees?
This question is motivated by a current  event, but I don't want to load it more than necessary by linking to it directly.

Mr X also said his government would have to do "everything we can to ensure that those who cannot and should not stay here in Y are repatriated and deported" and that deportations would be sped up if necessary.

Different people perceive immigration differently, but it seems to me that a significant proportion of voters are especially critical of cases where a refugee under a current deportation order remains in the country - perhaps on appeal - and then commits a crime.  When covered at length in the news it in turn hardens sentiments against refugees and immigrants.  Another aspect are expenses incurred by a state to provide for people it does not intend to allow to remain.
Are there any studies indicating, country by country, the average duration between a rejection/refusal to grant refugee status and the actual removal of that refugee?
Or, indeed a successful appeal and acceptance instead? - people taking years to obtain compassionate leniency can also be considered problematic.
Basically, how much time does it take between "you're not welcome here" and actual removal or acceptance?  Clearly, such an impactful process should not be performed without due deliberation, but neither do citizens seem to welcome the idea of that process taking years and that is what the unfortunate Mr. X is dealing with.
This question isn't meant to look at the wider pros and cons of the immigration/refugee debate.  Merely at the delay observed, by country, between refusal and removal.

p.s. too late to re-edit the text of the bounty, but answers providing solid numerical data other than across-the-board averages are also welcome.  Ex:  "60% of people are out within 2 years, 40% remain for indeterminate durations" would also qualify.
p.p.s. If people also want to look at how long it takes from initial detection to first formal interview to determine refugee eligibility, that would also seem relevant, as long as numbers are also provided.

I don't think a general answer is possible; there are cases in Germany where asylum is denied and refugees are required to leave, yet courts find that those same refugees cannot be deported because they are threatened at home ... so the system is lying to itself. Would those count?

AFAIK the vast majority of rejected asylum seekers from non-European countries are never removed, though some might leave out of their own volition. Whatever statistics you find need to be broken down by nationality/region to be meaningful. Deporting someone from Germany to Serbia or the U.S. is very easy. Deporting someone to Afghanistan is pretty much impossible. This is also why Australia had to use the Pacific Solution and intentionally made the Nauru camps horrible.

Both comments are valid qualifiers to this question - and, once supplemented by some actual numbers and sources - would make for possibly good answers.

I think "average" is going to be fairly meaningless.  The mean (or median) time that a person remains isn't going to be typical, nor even the centre of a vaguely normal distribution.

I think the more realistic question is what proportion of rejected/ ineligible refugees is deported at all (maybe within 10 years to make a well-defined question). Afaik that proportion is fairly low in most countries.

In some cases refugees can appeal against a decision to refuse asylum, and it seems appeals can take a long time, so not all who are refused asylum will eventually need to be removed. Do you count people who are appealing, or considering an appeal, or only those who have exhausted all appeals?

I am look at is date of "you're not wanted in country Y" vs date of "not in country Y"  or "you are accepted after all".  What activities and statuses fill that timeline isn't primarily the Q.  Merely how long it takes a country to enforce a decision.  Open for discussion:  if there is a bunch of recent arrivals who are "messing up the stats", it might be easiest to not count them.  "Recent" needs to be considered in the context of the A itself:  if they arrived 6 months ago and it has historically taken 5 years to deport people, then it's hard to use them to calculate anything.

Note that besides appeals against a rejection decision, people can also be granted the right to stay under other grounds than asylum (even if, depending on the country, laws can make it harder for them if they have been previously denied asylum, it may be still possible: it could happen that someone tried to apply for asylum to stay, when it would have been a way better idea for them in the first place to apply for a residence permit as a parent of a minor having the local nationality).

This is not a direct answer because Eurostat doesn't provide data on how long it takes to deport someone and doesn't clarify which deportees were denied asylum, but it should provide a broad overview of the situation in the EU.
Overall stats for illegal immigrants
This page from Eurostat provides a handy chart.

You're interested in the "Returned" numbers, which includes both voluntary and involuntary returns (deportations). 56.9% were forced returns, 43.1% were voluntary. Voluntary returns are most certainly undercounted (Germany reports 100% of their returns as involuntary, for example) but the involuntary ones should be accurate:

Between 2015 and 2023 there were a total of 8,416,355 people found to be illegally present and 1,261,270 were successfully returned, including both voluntary and involuntary returns. As a very rough estimate, this means that only 15% of illegal immigrants are successfully removed from the EU. If we generously assume that voluntary returns are undercounted by a factor of 3x, then approximately 28% of illegal immigrants end up leaving or 1.86x more than officially recorded.
Return success rate significantly depends on the country of origin
Here are the top 10 citizenships sorted by the total number of people found illegally in the EU between 2015 and 2023, as well as the percent that were successfully returned. The last column is percent returned multiplied by 1.86x, to try and account for undercounted voluntary departures.



Citizenship
Total illegal
Total returned
% returned
% returned * 1.86x




Syria
1881740
4315
0.23%
0.43%


Afghanistan
929960
19745
2.12%
3.95%


Iraq
486415
42595
8.76%
16.29%


Morocco
444650
49680
11.17%
20.78%


Ukraine
351575
110820
31.52%
58.63%


Albania
344895
131655
38.17%
71.00%


Pakistan
323915
19190
5.92%
11.02%


Algeria
320725
26165
8.16%
15.17%


Türkiye
245375
21015
8.56%
15.93%


Tunisia
226755
16650
7.34%
13.66%



Looking at the adjusted numbers we see that nationals of Syria (0.4%) and Afghanistan (4%) pretty much never get removed. Iraq (16%) or Morocco (21%) are a little easier to remove but the vast majority still end up staying. The highest on the list are Albania (71%) and Ukraine (59%), the only ones where the majority actually end up leaving.

Basically, how much time does it take between "you're not welcome here" and actual removal or acceptance?

For anywhere between 29% (Albania) and 99% (Syria) the answer is 'a lifetime' because they never get deported. It's easy to promise you'll "do everything we can to ensure that those who cannot and should not stay here in Y are repatriated and deported" but implementing this in practice would require a drastic ramp up of immigration enforcement.
The only country I'm aware of that successfully halted a massive influx of refugees is Australia, thanks Operation Sovereign Borders which began in 2013 and was a massive success:



Year
Illegals entering per year




2009
2726


2010
6555


2011
4565


2012
17204


2013
20587


2014-2024 (combined)
1224



That's right: in the past decade they've received 16x less illegal arrivals than in 2013 alone! But so far the only country that came close to copying the Australian approach was the UK, by passing the Rwanda Safety Act to start deporting illegal immigrants to Rwanda, similar to how Australia was doing it with Nauru. But the Conservatives lost the election, so this plan is now cancelled and immigration rules will likely continue to be unenforced for many years to come.

Afghanistan and Syria, of course, were the in midst of actively fought civil wars for all or almost all of the relevant period.

@ohwilleke Afghanistan has been as safe as it's ever been for ~3 years now, thanks to Taliban taking over control and establishing order. Still no sign of deportations.

Estimates are that 1041 died in 2023 and 769 died in 2024 so far in the ongoing civil war in Afghanistan under the Taliban. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_ongoing_armed_conflicts It is also a place where many deported persons would face a high likelihood of persecution upon return. And, critically, only China has diplomatic relations with the new regime, only since September 2023, and without formally recognizing it. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_relations_of_Afghanistan

@ohwilleke Realistically speaking this is as good as it gets, so if the EU still refuses to start deportations, then they'll never happen. Same thing with Syria, I guarantee nobody will be forcefully deported there even 20 years after the war is ~over because "deported persons would face a high likelihood of persecution upon return". Ironically the least problematic group of refugees (Ukrainians) is also the one that's most likely to be deported when their war is over :-)

I think your estimation of the source of the delay in Syria is likewise not right and that the core issue is non-recognition of the regime that controls part, but not all of Syria's territory as legitimate. Deportations only happen when a country is recognized diplmoatically.

@ohwilleke recognition of any given regime is entirely under the control of the German government, they could recognize Assad in Syria and Taliban in Afghanistan tomorrow and start the deportations. Most Syrian refugees are now approaching the 10-year mark, which is extremely dangerous...

... because after about 10-years activists will come out talking about how the kids of the refugees have grown up abroad and it would be cruel to send them back. See the DACA debacle in the US for an example of this happening across the ocean. To the credit of Germans they did send back most Yugoslav refugees after the war was over but that involved relocating people within Europe, which is more palatable to European voters. I would bet my entire life savings on Germany never deporting more than 5% of Afghani or Syrian illegal immigrants by force... [2]

... So unfortunately the quote by "Mr X" is pure kayfabe, an act designed to palate a certain spectrum of voters, but which will never be implemented in practice unless a far-right party gains a veto-proof majority in Parliament and ensures that the courts can't interfere with the immigration policy, which usually requires the party to stay in power for many years and be vigilant in pursuing judicial reforms. I.e. see how a single judge blocked the UK's Rwanda plan from being implemented in N. Ireland, undermining the very foundations of parliamentary supremacy. [3]

"extremely dangerous" hyperbole much? Having people born in Syria live in your country is not extremely dangerous. There are more than 187,000 Syrians in the U.S. and the sky has not fallen. They're down on their luck people, not ticking time bombs. Immigration is a low stakes game for countries, even though it is a high stakes game for immigrants themselves.

@ohwilleke based off data from 2016 asylum seekers were 15 times more likely to commit crime than native Germans. So you can see why some might want the law enforced. I’m sure the overall stats have improved since than thanks to most asylum seekers being Ukrainian nowadays but broken down by nationality I doubt things changed.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@ohwilleke 28 finally deported to Afghanistan today. Only 900,000 to go!

@JonathanReez 15 times more likely is only linking to a graphic in German, not even attributable to a particular article https:.. //pbs.twimg.com/media/DFhkrD_WAAEhdS5?format=jpg&name=large  Please take this comment down or substantiate it some more.  From recall, the Swedish police - which have been struggling with a partially immigrant-fueled crime problem - do not have anywhere near a 16x ratio, though they did admit there is an overrepresentation of immigrants in the stats.  Flagging as well, let's stick to verifiable references, esp on something as sensitive.

Otherwise, interesting answer.  I had no idea it was as bad.  I am especially curious why - if one avoids debatable cases like Syria and Afghanistan - so few get sent back to Morocco and Algeria.  The latter is certainly good enough to be buying natural gas from.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica my bad, forgot the source hyperlink for the crime stats. Like I said, 2023 data will certainly show a marked improvement but only thanks to a change in the countries of origins of refugees. I can’t find the Swedish stats from my phone by IIRC it was corroborated there, if focusing at certain countries of origin.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica not just illegal immigration is bad these days. The UK and Canada both set an all time immigration record last year, despite the Conservatives swearing to stop it for more than a decade. And unlike the illegal entries, issuing visas can be halted with one snap of the PMs finger, so there was no excuse there. They didn’t even do any sensible changes such as requiring passing a C1 language test to become a permanent resident, which would’ve at least increased the quality of people who get to stay permanently.

@JonathanReez Haha, the worthy EpochTimes.de is behind the 16x stat.  The Epoch Times was founded by John Tang and a group of Chinese-American Falun Gong practitioners. Overall, we rate The Epoch Times Right Biased and Questionable based on the publication of pseudoscience and the promotion of propaganda and conspiracy theories, as well as numerous failed fact checks.  Come on, you really ought to know better.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica here’s another source. Go to PDF 1 of “Tabeller”, then scroll to table B.6 to see relative risks. Afghanistan born citizens are 5x overrepresented in committing crimes. You can do an adjustment for age and gender (see further tables) but it clearly shows a big difference. Unfortunately they don’t provide a breakdown of asylum seekers specifically or numbers for serious crimes alone.

@ItalianPhilosophers4Monica the main report does have numbers for serious crimes (Figure 13). It shows that second generation people with two foreign born parents are even more dangerous than foreign born people. Up to 11x difference or 5x if adjusted for age/sex. Unfortunately they don’t have a breakdown per nationality here, just for immigrants overall. So the 15x number does pass the sniff test, if only looking at certain high-risk nations. And it shows the failure of integration, as the second generation is even worse.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

I don't necessarily share your uber-concern about immigration, but this answer comes closest to telling us what the overstay lengths look like.  Got very little sympathy for the populist right myself, but it's also not hard to see that not sending back rejected applicants in a timely fashion is going to annoy more and more people.

I'm not sure this answers all your questions (in particular the one about time to removal, after last failed appeal), but FWTW there is some summary data from 2016. Reflecting some of the comments [under the Q], two things stand out: timelines set by law are often exceeded in practice, at least for processing times, and the time it takes to reach a decision indeed vastly varies with the country of origin of the asylum applicant.




A number of countries (Netherlands, Switzerland, Italy, Hungary and Serbia) have laid down
deadlines shorter than 6 months for processing asylum applications under the regular procedure. These
have often proved difficult to comply with in recent practice, however. In Switzerland, despite a formal
time limit of 10 working days for deciding on asylum applications, the State Secretariat for Migration
(SEM) has reported an average processing time of 243.5 days in the first half of 2016. The first instance
procedure lasts on average 4-5 months in Hungary,
contrary to its 2-month deadline, while similar
difficulties to comply with deadlines are reported in Serbia.
Due to the large number of applications
received in Italy, the Territorial Commissions for International Protection have also failed to observe the
time limit of 33 days for deciding on asylum claims. More generally, however, European countries do
not seem to strictly abide by the 6-month deadline envisioned by the recast Asylum Procedures
Directive. By way of example, many asylum seekers in Austria have waited for over a year for their
personal interview in Austria, or six months in Sweden.


Many/several EU countries did not have any deadline for handling the [full] appeals procedure though (no table in the source, due to that):

Secondly, not all countries have introduced maximum deadlines for examining an asylum appeal, as
this was left to EU Member States’ discretion by the recast Asylum Procedures Directive.
For countries
that regulate this issue in domestic law, time limits may range from one month in Poland or two months
in Hungary and Serbia,
to five months in France and six months in Greece and Italy,
and to fifteen
months in Austria.
These time limits, binding on appeal authorities, are distinct from deadlines for
asylum seekers to lodge an appeal, which are not covered by this briefing.

Also, various EU countries have recently taken steps to change their time frames, at least in law. Sometimes the accelerations are decided by the executive--sometimes with weird results, e.g. someone is deported, imprisoned back in his home country, then the appeal for asylum 'succeeds' on appeal... in absentia. (And some of the recently proposed laws enshine the right of the executive to declare an emergency and implement [very] expedited 'procedures'.) And also changes at EU level are being proposed:

Another directive revises asylum procedures to fast-track deportations of people who have traveled via a “safe third country” or if they are from a country with recognition rates – the proportion of asylum applications that are approved from a given country of origin – below 20%.
Human rights groups criticize the pact because fast-track deportations are based on group characteristics, instead of individual review. They claim that the reforms also undermine the right of appeal – sometimes deporting people before an appeals decision is finalized – and expand detention.

Whether that will also be successful in practice, in terms of actual times...

A key to the acronyms in the chart would make it much easier to understand.

Yeah, sorry for that, there's a list of EU two-letter country codes here https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/statistics-explained/index.php?title=Glossary:Country_codes Also there's a more in-depth discussion of legislative changes on the return itself, particularly those changes made around 2018-2019, but on a quick scan, no statistics are presented for that, there.
